# Extract zero from 2D polynomial

Tags: polynomials, sums-of-squares, gradient-descent

If I have simple polynomial like this: $12 - 8 x - x^2 + x^3$ and I know that it has zero at x=2, I can get Taylor series near x=2, which is $5(x-1)^2$ and I get this picture:
[image: 1d polynomials]

So in 1D case I can naturally divide $(12 - 8 x - x^2 + x^3) / (x-1)^2$ = (x+3)/5 . And this division allows me to find second zero (x=-3) easily.

Now lets consider this 2D function $f = (x - y^2)^2 + (y - x^2)^2$:

[image: 2d case]

Its clear that $f>=0$ and has two zeroes $x=y=0$ and $x=y=1$. Taylor expansion near $x=y=0$ is $t = x^2 (1 - 2 y) + y^2 - 2 x y^2$. But it doesn't seem to be possible to divide $f$ by $t$ without getting some crazy fractionals.

My question is: is it possible somehow to transform f, so it no longer has root $x=y=0$, but still has only root $x=y=1$?

Answer (score 0):

You exemplary 1-dim polynomial is fine in itself, but it is not analogous to your 2-dim case.

The appropriate analogy should be something like:
$$g(x) = (x-1)^2 + (x-2)^2\, ,$$
where there are two squares showing the two roots.

I don't think this $g(x)$ can factored multiplicatively to "remove" one of the roots. The construct is additive in nature.

The same goes for your 2-dim contour. The multiplicative factorization you're asking doesn't exist.

btw, I think your original tag "sums-of-squares" is inappropriate, as it connects to posts mostly about tasks that are completely unrelated.